# Centered text in a square CSS box using borders?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a CSS box to act as a 'logo' piece or what have you, centered in another div on the middle of the page - I'm using bootstrap 3, put the div in a container-fluid for a full-width page as I wanted, and went about starting on the logo portion of it.

My code is as follows

```
 .logo{

    width: 50rem;
    height: 50rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15em;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif;
    color: white;
    border: 14px solid black;
}
```

For whatever reason, this doesn't actually make a square - I'm assuming this is based on the font-size, but it seems like the larger the font goes, it just spills outside of the box - so I can't for the life of me figure out how to both vertically align this text and create a perfect square around the text while I'm at it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: you can't use pixels for the width/height...?

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I thought I'd heard that would break potential responsiveness? Is this untrue?

Answer (score 0):

I have a container div that is basically that can be your body. The size can be adjusted.

Then there is the logo class. This class has a relative width. 
In the examples case: 50% of its parent (container class)

There is no fixed height of the box so it height is based on the text.

The box is positioned in the center trough absolute positioning and transforming it again.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 14px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    Some random text goes here?
  </div>
</div>
```